# I have to bind this function to option tag under select tag now when I am table rows only first row gets changed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

```jsp
<table id="t" border="1">
<thead id="tb">
    <tr>
        <th class="id">Id</th>
        <th class="name">Name</th>
        <th class="address">Address</th>
        <th class="phone">Phone</th>
        <th class="email">Email</th>
        <th class="age">Age</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <%
            while(rs.next()) {
        %>
        <td class="id" id="id" style="text-align: center;"><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
        <td class="name" id="na" style="text-align: center;"><%= rs.getString(2) %></td>
        <td class="address" id="ad" style="text-align: center;"><%= rs.getString(3) %></td>
        <td class="phone" id="ph" style="text-align: center;"><%= rs.getString(4) %></td>
        <td class="email" id="em" style="text-align: center;"><%= rs.getString(5) %></td>
        <td class="age" id="ag" style="text-align: center;"><%= rs.getString(6) %></td>

    </tr>
    <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
function click_action_2(){

   var y = document.getElementById("id");
   y.innerHTML = "xx";

   var x = document.getElementById("na");
   x.innerHTML = "xxxx";

   var z = document.getElementById("ad");
   z.innerHTML = "xx xxxx xxxx";

   var a = document.getElementById("ph");
   a.innerHTML = "xxxxxxxxxx";

   var b = document.getElementById("em");
   b.innerHTML = "xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx";

   var c = document.getElementById("ag");
   c.innerHTML = "xx";

}
```

I have bind this function to option tag under select tag now when I am changing rows only first row gets changed. Please help me out with better solution.

```js
$("select").bind('change', function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "1":
            click_action_1();
            break;

        case "2":
            click_action_2();
            break;

        case "3":
            click_action_3();
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code that is intended to change rows looks like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id-of-element");
element.innerHTML = "whatever";
```

What's happening here is you are selecting a **single** element (using the id) and then changing **that specific element.**

There is a difference between `id` and `class` on elements. The `id` is supposed to be unique across the entire document. If you use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), you will always get only one element. When you want to change a *set* of elements (a bunch of rows, in your case), you would probably use the `class` to select them all.

In plain JavaScript (without jQuery), that could be done using [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). These functions will return a set of elements that you can then iterate over to change.

```
var elements = document.getElementByClassName('class-of-elements');

for (var i = elements.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = 'whatever';
}
```

If you use jQuery (I see it in the `$("select").bind` area), it's a little simpler:

```
$('.class-of-elements').html('whatever');
```

What's happens first here is the selection of the elements (notice that the class begins with the `.` just like in CSS). At that point, we are dealing with a jQuery collection of elements. The [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function lets you access the `innerHTML` of all the elements. Passing a string will set the `innerHTML` for each element to that string.